# Convert Dates to values on an X axis

Tags: date-and-time, fitting

I have a bunch of dates and values which I put into the DateListPlot to get a graph. However I would also like to put this information into the Fit or LeastSquares to estimate what the value would be today. So far I have this

```
DateListPlot[{{{1991, 4, 1}, 100}, {{1991, 4, 1}, 110}, {{1993, 6, 1},
    120}, {{1994, 4, 1}, 129}, {{1996, 4, 10}, 130}, {{1999, 2, 2}, 
   140}, {{2004, 4, 6}, 150}, {{1999, 8, 22}, 155}, {{2003, 4, 1}, 
   160}, {{2005, 5, 9}, 200}, {{2003, 12, 3}, 174}, {{2005, 11, 4}, 
   193}, {{2012, 7, 1}, 212}, {{2009, 12, 12}, 232}}]
```

The output is a graph of course but I had hoped I could do something like

`Coordinates=DateListPlot[...]`

And then send that into Fit or something. The problem here is converting the date values into some numbers which could be used with Fit. For example I could convert every day since April 1st 1991 into the new x value but that isn't really an elegant solution. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Alright I will do as best as I can but I am really new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See AbsoluteTime...

e.g. `AbsoluteTime[{1999,1,1}]` returns the number of seconds from 1st Jan 1970 to that date.

In full...

```
Fit[{AbsoluteTime[#1] - AbsoluteTime[{1991, 4, 1}], #2} & @@@ {{{1991,
      4, 1}, 100}, {{1991, 4, 1}, 110}, {{1993, 6, 1}, 
    120}, {{1994, 4, 1}, 129}, {{1996, 4, 10}, 130}, {{1999, 2, 2}, 
    140}, {{2004, 4, 6}, 150}, {{1999, 8, 22}, 155}, {{2003, 4, 1}, 
    160}, {{2005, 5, 9}, 200}, {{2003, 12, 3}, 174}, {{2005, 11, 4}, 
    193}, {{2012, 7, 1}, 212}, {{2009, 12, 12}, 232}}, {1, x}, x]
```

Comment: Yes with this I could simply plot both the coordinates and this graph, thanks.

Comment: no need to subtract off the initial time here, if you remove that then you can do `Plot[fit, {x, AbsoluteTime[{1991, 4, 1}], AbsoluteTime[{2009, 12, 12}]}]` which can be directly combined with the `DateListPlot`